# Nontrivial solutions to $\sum f(x) - \int f(x) = \gamma $?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, asymptotics, monotone-functions, euler-mascheroni-constant

Consider

$$ T(f) = \lim_{t \to \infty} \sum_{i =1}^t f(i) - \int_1^t f(x) dx $$

Notice $ T(a + b) = T(a) + T(b) $ and $T(C a) = C T(a)$ when $C $ is a constant.
Also $T(0)= 0$.

Let $T(d) = 0$.
So $T(1/x + d) = \gamma $

Now i Know sophomore's dream , so that is 1 solution to $d$ that is nontrivial.

Also $T(x^{-a}) = \zeta(a) - \frac{1}{a-1}$.

I wonder , is there a solution or many such that

$T(v) = \gamma $

Such that $v$ is no asymptotic of $\ln $ ?

In particular a solution $v_2$ such that both the sum and integral converge ?? And another one $v_3 $ where both the sum and integral diverge.

Both existence and closed forms are considered .

Also of particular interest are those $T(g) $ solutions above where for $x ≥ 1$ we have ,$ g '(x) $ is always the same sign.

Comment: $$ |\sum-\int| \leq max(f(1), f(t)) $$

Comment: Yes that is true. So that shows ... Existence ??

Answer (score 0):

This is perhaps not quite in the spirit of the question, but if $f(x)$ is a solution, so is
$$ g(x) = f(x)-f(\lfloor x \rfloor); $$
the sum is identically zero, the integral converges if and only if the limit exists, and therefore $g$ will not be asymptotic to $\log$.

As for a divergent solution, $T(c)$ is defined and equal to zero for constant $c$, so $T(g+c)=T(g)$ for any $c$, while the sum is equal to $tc$ and the integral is $-tc + \int_0^t g$, both of which diverge if $c \neq 0$.

As for solutions with a derivative of constant sign, consider $f(x)=r^x$. The sum is
$$ \frac{r}{1-r}(1-r^t), $$
while the integral is
$$ -\frac{r}{\log{r}}(1-r^{t-1}). $$
Supposing that $0<r<1$, taking the limit gives
$$ \frac{r}{1-r} + \frac{r}{\log{r}}. $$
One can show that this is a positive increasing function that maps $(0,1) \to (0,1/2)$. Hence one can find many nontrivial convergent solutions this way: for $0<r<1$,
$$ T(ar^x) = a\left(\frac{r}{1-r} + \frac{r}{\log{r}} \right), $$
and one can find $a,r$ so that the right-hand side is $\gamma$ provided that $a>2\gamma$, and any $a$ gives exactly one such $r$.

Comment: But a and r are not closed form. They are functions of eulers gamma itself that do not reduce to standard forms. The Floor idea is ok but not analytic and trivial. +1 but No accept.